# add css Style to dynamic columnclasses in JSFpanelGrid

Tags: css, jsf, dynamic

I have JSF panelGrid which no of columns are dynamic ,in this case how should i declare the columnclasses in css ?

```
<h:panelGrid id="testpanel" columns="#{message.no_of_columns}" rows="#{message.no_of_rows}" columnClasses="">
```

I want to have same css style for all the columns.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either generate a commaseparated string with as many items as the number of columns:

```
<h:panelGrid ... columnClasses="#{message.columnClasses}">
```

Or redefine the style so that it can be applied at table level:

```
<h:panelGrid ... styleClass="dynamicGrid">
```

with

```
.dynamicGrid td {
    /* Put the original CSS here, it'll get applied to every column. */
}
```

Comment: hi Thanks for your answer,i have one more doubt.now able set css property.im getting background color code from db.
<h:hiddenInput value={colorEBean.colorCode},how do i pass this value to my css class?
.dynamicGrid td
 {
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 border: 4px solid gray;
        background:
}

Comment: can i use to javascript to do this? i tried this onload script but failed,

Comment: Your initial question has been answered. If you have a new question, press `Ask Question` button.